# Is it possible to add a page or replace a page in mupdf library?

Tags: android, ios, pdf, mupdf

I'm using mupdf in one of my project. It nearly meets almost my requirement except that I don't know if it supports to add new page or replace a new page?

The demo of mupdf shows how to add a layer to the current page (draw on the page) and save it. But I can't find the function to add new page and delete page. Can anybody advise? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some hints/ideas.

I'm not so sure that is available such method with the java jni wrapper.

But MuPDF allow you to add/delete a page. 
If you look at the source code [include/mupdf/pdf/document.h](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=include/mupdf/pdf/document.h;h=8c71d88bb9d8b24be9fd3a979e893249fbba8bf0;hb=HEAD):

```
pdf_page *pdf_create_page(pdf_document *doc, fz_rect rect, int res, int rotate);
void pdf_delete_page(pdf_document *doc, int number);
void pdf_delete_page_range(pdf_document *doc, int start, int end);
```

If you know C, you could try to add your jni wrapper functions to [platform / android / jni / mupdf.c](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=platform/android/jni/mupdf.c)

Comment: That's great. Thank you much. I'll definitely try it.Does that mean I can use these functions directly in ios? Honestly I'm familiar with c but not familiar with uni. I only know it's a native interface for java app to call it.

Comment: You are welcome! jni is very awful :-) but ig you google you will find a lot of great tutorials. I'm not an iOS developer, but I think that you could use it directly.

Comment: MuPDF is intended to be used from C. The JNI bindings are currently not intended to be used in anything other than the way the demo applications use them, and are subject to change without any notice at all. In the future we hope to have a defined and stable JNI interface but at present the intention is to use C to drive MuPDF.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. It helps a lot.Another question is how I should use pdf_document *doc? It seems I only have a fz_document.

Comment: Sorry. I think I know already. pdf_document *pdf_specifics(fz_document *doc)

Comment: I managed to implement the function to create and insert a new blank page in ios. The next step will be the conversion of a UIImage to a image for mupdf. Any more hints ?

Comment: As i wrote, I'm sorry, but I'm not an iOS developer. Try to convert the UIImage in jpeg and then look at the mupdf apis, try  (source/pdf/pdf-image.c). Good luck! :-)

Comment: I can convert an ios UIImage to a bitmap. But I don't know how to add this bitmap to mupdf. The functions in pdf-image.c seems used to load images from document. But I can't find a function to add the image to pdf.

Comment: I found a function fz_new_pixmap_with_data. But I still have no idea how am I supposed to add fz_pixmap to the pdf page or doc.